# When I search score:-100 and click 1010502 it says We couldn't find anything for your search

Tags: bug, search

When I search like this : `score:-100` there are many results(when I serched, there was 1010502 pages (may be different))

[image: page]

But when I click the go to <kbd>1010502</kbd> page button it says like this

> We couldn't find anything for your search
> **Search options:** score>= -100
> Try different or less specific keywords.

[image: error]

Why this happens?

Comment: from page 1000001 onwards (till 1010502), you are seeing 0 results: try it: [`https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000001&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000001&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100). My guess is that from here onwards you are getting deleted-questions (that you can see if you are >10k rep)

Comment: Could this be and XY problem? I suspect the query you want is something like `score:..-100` or similar.

Comment: @user000001 what's an and XY problem?

Comment: @ppwater (read the meta: [What is the XY problem? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By experiment (confirmed by [Yatin in their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401744/when-i-search-score-100-and-click-1010502-it-says-we-couldnt-find-anything-for#comment799903_401744)) it looks like the cut off is at 1,000,000 pages.

[Page 1,000,000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000000&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100&mixed=0) gives 50 results.

[Page 1,000,001](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000001&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100&mixed=0) gives 0 results. That are not deleted posts.

[8 year old posts, page 1,000,000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000000&tab=Relevance&q=created%3a-8y&mixed=0) gives 50 results

[8 year old posts, page 1,000,001](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000000&tab=Relevance&q=created%3a-8y&mixed=0) gives 0 results

As those high number pages takes for ever to load there might be both a performance and sanity trade-off. I don't think it was expected users would be interested in the tail end of a search with > 1,000,000 pages, let alone skip through from the start till the end. Expect this to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

If you're using search to gather statistics or research extreme cases / outliers, consider using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) instead which comes with an [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by
the magnificent [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio)

Comment: Just as an extra data point, it seems like the cut-off is 50 million results, not a particular page number: the last page is [#1666666 with 30 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1666666&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100&pagesize=30) and [#3333333 with 15 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3333333&tab=Relevance&q=score%3a-100&pagesize=15).